# returning blank as underscore

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

I need to have an underscore for any space in the last part of this address returned from a mysql table. The problem is I don't think I can just modify the SQL in the model because I need to have the original values with spaces returned in the `value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>"` portion as well. I am just starting to learn php/html so not sure if this is possible. Here is the portion of the code from the view that I need to modify.

`<?php foreach($rb_data as $row){ ?>`

`<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>" onClick="document.location.href = ('http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/controller/community/<?php echo $row['brand'];?>   ' );">`

`<?php } ?>`

For example when I click on the button that says Our Family I need it to return  `CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/controller/community/our_family` 
all lowercase is preferred but not necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($rb_data as $row){ ?>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>" onClick="document.location.href = ('http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/controller/community/<?php echo str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($row['brand']));?> ' );">

<?php } ?>
```

if you only need to replace spaces you could do something like that.

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks for the prompt reply MaggiQall!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use CI handy helper function url_title() you need to load URL helper

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $row['brand'];?>" onClick="document.location.href = ('http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/controller/community/<?php echo url_title($row['brand'],'_');?> ' );">

<?php } ?>
```

if you are not giving second parament in url_tilte it will have dash - by default if you are setting _ or somthing

[URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip. I will be looking into that as well.

Comment: i just found on CI docs if you pass third param in url_title it will change the case of string from upper to lower <?php echo url_title($row['brand'],'_',TRUE);?>